# How to use zoom for array of pictures?

Tags: javascript

I need a zoom gallery.
I like this code because it's short.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_zoom.asp

But it uses id, so I cant't use it for building gallery.

I changed id's to classes, but it doesn't work.

How can I change this code to use classes?

Comment: You're probably better off [using a **library** for this](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=gallery).

Comment: Just curious: Why can't you use IDs?

Comment: I cant`t use id`s because I have dynamic array of pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with dynamic IDs. I created a snippet, where there are 4 different images with different IDs - and the zooming effect works.

I think it's easier to do it this way than to rewrite the **zooming** feature for `class`es.

```js
// list of images
// with RANDOM IDs!
const images = [{
    id: Date.now() - 400,
    src: 'https://loremflickr.com/1200/960/girl/all?random=1'
  },
  {
    id: Date.now() - 200,
    src: 'https://loremflickr.com/1200/960/girl/all?random=2'
  },
  {
    id: Date.now() + 200,
    src: 'https://loremflickr.com/1200/960/girl/all?random=3'
  },
  {
    id: Date.now() + 400,
    src: 'https://loremflickr.com/1200/960/girl/all?random=4'
  },
];

// displaying images
(function(images) {

  let html = ''
  images.forEach(image => {
    html += `
      <h2>ID: ${ image.id }</h2>
      <div class="img-zoom-container d-flex">
        <img id="${ image.id }" src="${image.src}" width="300" height="240" alt="Girl">
        <div id="${ image.id }-result" class="img-zoom-result"></div>
      </div>
      <hr />
    `
  })
  const container = document.getElementById('container')
  container.innerHTML = html

  const imagelist = document.querySelectorAll('.img-zoom-container > img')

  // adding event listener for the random IDs
  imagelist.forEach(image => {
    image.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
      imageZoom(e.target.id, `${ e.target.id }-result`)
    })
  })

})(images);


// code from W3 Schools
// https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_zoom.asp
function imageZoom(imgID, resultID) {
  var img, lens, result, cx, cy;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  result = document.getElementById(resultID);
  /* Create lens: */
  lens = document.createElement("DIV");
  lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
  /* Insert lens: */
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
  /* Calculate the ratio between result DIV and lens: */
  cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
  cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
  /* Set background properties for the result DIV */
  result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  result.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";
  /* Execute a function when someone moves the cursor over the image, or the lens: */
  lens.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  /* And also for touch screens: */
  lens.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);

  function moveLens(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /* Prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image */
    e.preventDefault();
    /* Get the cursor's x and y positions: */
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    /* Calculate the position of the lens: */
    x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
    y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
    /* Prevent the lens from being positioned outside the image: */
    if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {
      x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;
    }
    if (x < 0) {
      x = 0;
    }
    if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {
      y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;
    }
    if (y < 0) {
      y = 0;
    }
    /* Set the position of the lens: */
    lens.style.left = x + "px";
    lens.style.top = y + "px";
    /* Display what the lens "sees": */
    result.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
  }

  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0,
      y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /* Get the x and y positions of the image: */
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /* Calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image: */
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /* Consider any page scrolling: */
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {
      x: x,
      y: y
    };
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.img-zoom-container {
  position: relative;
}

.img-zoom-lens {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  /*set the size of the lens:*/
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.img-zoom-result {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  /*set the size of the result div:*/
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```